# Centering the title of the Index page without affecting the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, indexing, imakeidx

I have the following document. I would like to center the title of the index page. The problem is that in the table of contents, this title becomes centered which is undesirable (see the image below). Is there a way to fix this?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\renewcommand*{\indexname}{\makebox[1.0\linewidth]{my index name}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\index{hello}
\chapter*{\makebox[1.0\linewidth]{List of notations}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of notations}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\indexname` is only meant to hold the index title, but not any formatting. Define `\indexname` to be your special index title and modify the formatting of `\chapter` headers separately, using the `sectsty` package. `\chapterfont{\centering}` switches to centered chapter headings; you can switch back by `\chapterfont{\raggedright}`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\renewcommand*{\indexname}{my index name}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}
\section{First section}
\index{hello}
\chapterfont{\centering}%
\chapter*{List of notations}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of notations}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Many thanks, I think in this  new solution the title of the table of contents is also getting centered. So perhaps the image should be updated. I think your previous solution modified by  `\xpatchcmd\theindex{\indexname}{\makebox[1.0\linewidth]{\indexname}}{}{}` is also working

Comment: @Name I think I've found a cleaner solution using the `sectsty` package, no hacking needed.